# Where is the .config hidden on Samsung Galaxy S4?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, kernel

> cat /proc/config.gz
>   tmp-mksh: cat: /proc/config.gz: No such file or directory

Is there another place to find it?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! It's not quite clear what you're asking for here. Could you please [edit] your question and add some more details? What kind of `.config` file should that be, and what for do you need it?

Comment: Do not close this question. It has been answered, and seems like a valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/proc/config.gz` (and consequently `.config`), a file containing all needed flags for the Linux kernel building process, can only be found if the kernel maker / your device manufacturer explicitly enabled `config.gz` availability when the Linux kernel was being built.

So if it's not present in `/proc`, you'd have to either do a trial-and-error, get help from somebody else, or contact the manufacturer.

Comment: I can confirm this. It's not stored on the device at all. You need to find the right kernel build options elsewhere.

Comment: @Dan Hulme  The .config 'stock' is not available period. I found a custom ROM image and used that. The the blacklist feature on the partitions bricked my phone. Samsung/AT&T engineers got me.